# The meaning of the term "lies" above the x-axis

Tags: polynomials

On my math quiz there was an equation that produced a polynomial that starts positive, crosses the x axis at negative 3, and then stays negative. There was a true or false question that asked if the graph lies above the x-axis when x < -1. I knew that the graph was negative after -3 but before the intercept the graph was positive so therefore in my thinking the graph did lie above the x-axis making me say true. She claims it was false an is unwilling to negotiate. Who is right?

This is a link to a picture of the quiz
http://s30.postimg.org/3wwgpra69/image.jpg

Comment: *"I knew that the graph was negative after -3 but before the intercept the graph was positive so therefore in my thinking the graph did lie above the x-axis making me say true."* Didn't the question ask about for $x<-1$, though? If it had asked for $x<-3$, I think your answer would have been correct.

Comment: By the way: your teacher should not *negotiate*, but she should definitely *explain* to you why that statement is false. Did you ask her to explain her claim?

Comment: If "the graph has a hole at" is a synonym for "the function is not defined for", then indeed d) is the only true statement in that picture.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that a set of points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ *lies above the $x$-axis* if **all** the points in that set have positive ordinate, i.e. if their second component is $>0$.

If you call your polynomial $p(x)$, then the question asks you if all the points $(x,y)$ in the graph $\Gamma = \{(x,p(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ with $x < -1$ have $y > 0$, which is false because, as you say yourself, $y < 0$ for every point in $\Gamma$ with $x < -3$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous at best since *most* of it lies above the $x$-axis but some of it doesn't.  If you could post the question verbatim it'd be most helpful and you'd get a more solid answer.