# Math quiz ambiguity

Tags: graphing-functions

This is a picture of my math quiz in which I got a question wrong.

[image]

I feel I should not lose points as the question is to ambiguous. I assumed that if one point lied above x-axis then that would constitute as the graph lying above the x-axis. My teacher interpreted it as all points must lie above. Is she right?

Comment: You asked this question already at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195770/the-meaning-of-the-term-lies-above-the-x-axis -- if you had additional questions about the answers there, it would be better to ask them there rather than re-post the question.

Comment: There's a semantic difference between "when[ever]" and "for some"

Answer (score 2):

Note $x<-1$ refers to *all* of the points less than $-1$ so no, one point is not enough.

Yes your teacher is correct under the usual conventions.